# Parsing json string generated from org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroAsTextInputFormat using python streaming

Tags: python, json, hadoop

In hadoop streaming using python for reading avro data file I am using the input format, which doc says the input key is string representation in JSON.

```
-inputformat org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroAsTextInputFormat
```

The mapper gets this as a line input:

```
line = "{u'three': u'3', u'two': u'2', u'one': u'1'}"
```

How do I parse this string, to get the key value pairs?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```
>>> line = "{u'three': u'3', u'two': u'2', u'one': u'1'}"
>>> line
"{u'three': u'3', u'two': u'2', u'one': u'1'}"
>>> import ast
>>> mydict = ast.literal_eval(line)
>>> mydict
{u'one': u'1', u'three': u'3', u'two': u'2'}
>>> for key in mydict:
    print key, mydict[key]

one 1
three 3
two 2
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i need. I hope this solution works with if input contains the arrays also.